# gmaps.js mouseover open infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, gmaps.js

I using gmaps.js to display simple map with some markers, but I want show infowindows with mouseover, I can't find how to do it.
My code:

```
    map = new GMaps({
    scrollwheel: false,
    div: '#gmap',
    lat: -12,
    lng: -77,
});

map.addMarker({
    lat: -12,
    lng: -77,
    title: 'test',
    infoWindow:{
        content: '<p>HTML Content</p>'
    },
    mouseover: function(e){
        this['infowindow'].open(map, this); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
            mouseover: function(e){
                this.infoWindow.open(this.map, this);
            }
```